# How to use InstagramWrapper APi C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, instagram-api

Hello there I working with api newly in this field so plz help me to understand .. how to use this api i want to login with instagram and get user photo ...

```
        InstaConfig ic = new InstaConfig();

        ic.redirect_uri = " http://localhost";
        ic.client_secret = "******";
        ic.client_id = "*******"; 
       var user = ia.GetAccessToken(code,ic); //// what is the **Code** im geting red line  ???? asking for ..
```

and how to continue with app .. i have look every where i cant find any help ... plz any one help how login with the and get data .. http://instagram.com/developer/authentication/ .... not helping with C# 
i get help form this link https://github.com/cagrik/csharp-instagram-wrapper ....

Comment: Please specify the specific (compiler) error you get. Also show us where the "code" variable is declared and / or assigned.

Comment: the CODE is api
 public InstagramWrapper.Model.OuthUser GetAccessToken(string code, InstagramWrapper.Model.InstaConfig ic)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on InstaAPI (C# Wrapper for Instagram API) on [**github**](https://github.com/yuvrajb/InstaAPI) and [**codeplex**](https://instaapi.codeplex.com/)

---

To login and access logged-in user's photo:

```
List<Scope> scopes = new List<Scope>() { Scope.basic };
InstaConfig config = new InstaConfig("CLIENT_ID", "CLIENT_SECRET", "REDIRECT_URI", scopes);

// use this to redirect user for authenticating your application
String AuthenticationUriString = config.GetAuthenticationUriString(); 

OAuth oauth = new OAuth(config, "CODE_ATTACHED_WITH_REDIRECTEDURI_AFTERSUCCESSFUL_AUTHENTICATION");
AuthUser user = oauth.GetAuhtorisedUser();

Console.WriteLine(user.AccessToken);
Console.WriteLine(user.UserId);
Console.WriteLine(user.UserName);
Console.WriteLine(user.FullName);
Console.WriteLine(user.ProfilePicture);
```